# ActiveRecord has_many where child model is greater than 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to solve a seemingly simple AR problem I'm having. I can't figure out how to return a list of events that have 1 or more attendees, and the docs examples use `cache_control` which I don't want to use.

I have a simple event model with a `has_many` relationship:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendees
end
```

and an attendees model that belongs to event

```
class Attendees < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

But some events will have 0 attendees. So what's the ActiveRecord way of doing this without using `cache_control` or writing a custom SQL statement?

It seems like it would be something like:

`Event.where(attendees.count > 0)`

but I keep getting a column error.

Comment: your model class is  `Atendee` or `Atendees` ?

Answer (score 0):

To get only events with attendees you can do:  `Event.joins(:attendees).uniq.all`

Calling `all` at the end returns an array whereas dropping it will leave you with an activerecord relation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `where` method chained with not to do this

```
Event.where.not(id: Attendee.select(:event_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a [`LEFT INNER JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join) only records with a match in the join table will be returned. So you don't actually need to perform a count.

```
Event.joins(:attendees)
```

Will thus only give you events which have attendees. The opposite would be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which returns rows from `events` even if there is no corresponding rows in `attendees`.

Counter caches on the other hand can be beneficial for performance since it avoids a `COUNT` query on the associated table if you want to use a lazy loading association. This can be useful when using fragment caching or if the query to the associated table is expensive.

```
<%# counter cache avoids query %>
<% cache(event) do %>
<ul>
  <%# only perform query if cache is stale %>
  <% event.attendees.each do |a| %> 
  <li><%= link_to a.name, a %></li>
  <% end %>
<ul>
<% end if event.attendees.any? %>
```

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: If you really wanted to do a count you would need to join the table or perform a subselect. Your approach does not work since the `attendees` table is not in the `FROM` clause in the query.